# How to create vertical or horizontal guideline programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I need to create guidelines programmatically, and apply views to these guideline.

I used following code but its crashing.

```
  Guideline guideline = new Guideline(this);
  guideline.setId(guideline.generateViewId());
  constraintLayout.addView(guideline);


//Connecting view with the guideline


        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT,   guideline.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

but i am getting following error message.

> java.lang.AssertionError: LEFT

I am also unable to understand how to apply orientation to the guideline i created

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting the error because the orientation is not set. However, that is only one issue that you have in your code. This is one area of *ConstraintLayout* that I find a little murky. Here is how I understand to build a guideline programmatically. See the comments in the code for an explanation.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);

        // Create our guideline and add it to the layout.
        Guideline guideline = getNewGuideline(this, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.VERTICAL);
        constraintLayout.addView(guideline);
        // Once the view is added to the layout, we can set its position.
        guideline.setGuidelinePercent(0.25f);

        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        // The layout has a ConstraintSet already, so we have to get a clone of it to manipulate.
        set.clone(constraintLayout);
        // Now we can make the connections. All of our views and their ids are available in the
        // ConstraintSet.
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        set.connect(textView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, guideline.getId(), ConstraintSet.END);
        set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    }

    private Guideline getNewGuideline(Context context, int orientation) {
        Guideline guideline = new Guideline(context);
        guideline.setId(Guideline.generateViewId());
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.orientation = orientation;
        guideline.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return guideline;
    }
}
```